# Rewrite a URL in PlayFrameWork

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1

I want to rewrite a URL from `http://SystemName:9000/` to `http://tpsystem:9000/`

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: The URL and port number is governed by where you choose to run the Play server from.

Answer (score 0):

This is linked to the machine on which you are running your application on.

I guess you should have a look at some DNS stuff.